# Query on lambda calculus addition

Tags: lambda-calculus

How do I add two numbers in lambda calculus using below given arithmetic representation of addition?

```
m + n = λx.λy.(m x) (n x) y
2 = λa.λb.a (a b)
3 = λa.λb.a (a (a b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You know what 2 is, what 3 is, and what addition is. Take the values and just stick 'em into the operation!

```
2 + 3 = (λx.λy.(m x) (n x) y) (λa.λb.a (a b)) (λa.λb.a (a (a b)))
        |-------- + --------| |----- 2 -----| |------- 3 -------|
```

This is an application with a lambda on the left. Such a term is called a *redex*, and it can be β-reduced. The actual reduction is left as an exercise for the reader.